# Pandas Pivot table aggfunc countif condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to make a pivot table of dataset Docs that counts the number of 'DocuNum' and count if only 'DaysBetween' column is less than 30.  My pivot table should have two columns.  Count of 'DocNum' and count of 'Days Between' less than 30.

```
DocsPivot = pd.pivot_table(Docs, index = ['Study'], values = ['DocNum', 
            'DaysBetween'],  
            aggfunc ={'DocNum':len, 'DaysBetween':lambda x: x<30})
```

Expected Result

```
TEST    DocNum  DaysBetween 
101 4158    365
203 1958    325
105 1019    243
201 11922   1045
204 1067    56
301 2690    265
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change `x<30` to `(x<30).sum()`

```
DocsPivot = pd.pivot_table(Docs, index = ['Test'], values = ['DocNum', 
            'DaysBetween'],  
            aggfunc ={'DocNum':len, 'DaysBetween':lambda x: (x<30).sum()})
```